# Вопрос о ключевых ( именованных ) аргументах

Tags: python

Python разработан так , что при вызове функции указание позиционного аргумента после ключевого вызывает ошибку :

```
def sum (a,b) : 
    return a + b 

print (sum(b = 3,5)) # синтаксическая ошибка
```

Здесь всё понятно : 2 значения попадают в 1 параметр `b` , а параметр `a` остаётся без значения . Но даже если указать аргументы "правильно" , получится синтаксическая ошибка :

```
def sum (a,b) : 
    return a + b 

print (sum(a = 3,5)) # синтаксическая ошибка
```

Сначала я подумал , что это сделано , чтобы программисты по случайности не отправляли 2 значения в 1 параметр . Но такую - же ошибку можно допустить , если указать позиционный аргумент перед ключевым :

```
def sum (a,b) : 
    return a + b 

print (sum(3,a=5)) # два значения в одном параметре
```

Вопрос : зачем разработчики языка запретили указывать ключевые аргументы перед позиционными , если даже соблюдая правило можно получить ошибку по той - же причине ?

Comment: В третьем случае тоже, кстати, Python отругается, вы не сможете такой вариант запустить. Ну просто такое правило, чтобы убрать неоднозначности. Сначала позиционные аргументы, а потом уже именованные. И не называйте свои функции так же, как встроенные функции Python, потом сюрприз будет, когда вы захотите использовать встроенную функцию `sum`, а Python вместо неё будет использовать вашу функцию.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Язык запрещает указание позиционных аргументов после ключевых, потому что непонятно, как определять, к какому позиционному аргументу обращаются - к первому сначала или к первому после ключевого.

```
def foo(a=1, b=2, c=3):
    print(a, b, c)

foo(1, c=4) # i-ый позиционный аргумент к i-ому параметру, всё ОК
# foo(b=1, 2) # 2 относится к a или к c?
```

В случае указания всех аргументов (2 ключевых явно и 1 позиционный явно) это можно сделать, но это усложнит язык, нарушая принцип из [The Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/):

> Special cases aren't special enough to break the rules.